# Predicted circular regression curve from a bpnr regression

Tags: regression, data-visualization, interpretation, circular-statistics

I'm trying to understant how to interpretresults from the bpnreg package to do glm on a circular response variable (flight directions).
I understood from the paper that the interpretation can be done using the SAM and AC parameters.

I've started with a very simple example, and tryed to reproduce the Predicted circular regression curves we can see int the tutorial:Cremers, Jolien, Kees Tim Mulder, et Irene Klugkist. « Circular Interpretation of Regression Coefficients ». British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology 71, nᵒ 1 (février 2018): 75‑95. https://doi.org/10.1111/bmsp.12108.

I tried applying this formula number (6) :
predicted angle= ac + arctan[bc(x-ax)]
But this doesn't seem to correspond to the predicted angles ?
If anyone knows what I am missing ?

Here is my code :

```
#Simulated data :
b <- seq(-20,19, by=1) 
angles <- 2 - 4*b + rnorm(mean=0,sd=10,40)
plot(angles ~ b)

angles_c_D <- circular(angles,units = "degrees", template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi")
angles_c_D_180 <- angleRemap(angles_c_D)
angles_c_R <- deg2rad(angles_c_D_180)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(angles_c_R,b))
data$angles_c_R <- circular(angles,units = "radians", template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi")

fit.Maps <- bpnr(pred.I = angles_c_R ~ 1+ b, data=data, its = 10000, burn = 1000, n.lag = 3, seed = 101)

Then Predicted circular regression curve for the relation between b and the angles :

newdata <- seq(min(b),max(b),length.out= dim(data)[[1]])
pred <- fit.Maps $ circ.coef [,"mean ac"] + atan( fit.Maps $circ.coef[,"mean bc"]*(newdata -  fit.Maps$circ.coef[,"mean ax"] ) )

pred_degr <-  rad2deg(pred)

plot(as.numeric(angles_c_D_180) ~ b,ylim=c(-180,180))
points(pred_degr ~ newdata,type="l")
```

Comment: Hi! I can probably help, but could you make your code reproducible by adding the definition of the functions such as `angleRemap`, as well as your imports?

Comment: Hi, thank you, I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
Below the functions I used.
I think I fixed the problem and my formula for the regression curve is correct ?

````
rad2deg <- function(rad) {(rad * 180) / (pi)}
deg2rad <- function(deg) {(deg * pi) / (180)}

angleRemap <- function(theta) {toRad <- atan2(1, 1)/45
atan2(sin(toRad * theta), cos(toRad * theta))/toRad}

library(bpnreg)
library(circular)
library(truncnorm)

#simulate correlated data
b <- seq(-20,19.5, by=0.1) 
i =20 ; slope = 5 
angles <- 20 - 5*b + rtruncnorm(396, a=-180  - min(i - slope*b ) , b=180 - max(i - slope*b ), mean = 0, sd = 40) # I used truncnorm to stay between -180 and 180

angles_c_D <- circular(angles,units = "degrees", template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi")
angles_c_D_180 <- angleRemap(angles_c_D)
angles_c_R <- deg2rad(angles_c_D)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(angles_c_R,b))
data$angles_c_R <- circular(data$angles_c_R ,units = "radians", template = "geographics", modulo = "2pi")

fit <- bpnr(angles_c_R ~ b, data=data, its = 30000, burn = 10000, n.lag = 3, seed = 101)

# Predicted circular regression curve for the relation between b and the 

b1 <- min(b)
b2 <- max(b)
newdata <- seq(b1,b2,length.out= dim(data)[[1]])
pred <- fit$circ.coef[,"mean ac"] + atan( fit$circ.coef[,"mean bc"]*(newdata -  fit$circ.coef[,"mean ax"] ) )
pred_degr <-  rad2deg(pred)

predbis <- atan2( fit$lin.coef.II[1,"mean"]  + b*fit$lin.coef.II[2,"mean"],fit$lin.coef.I[1,"mean"]  + b*fit$lin.coef.I[2,"mean"]  )
predbis_degre <- rad2deg(predbis)

plot(as.numeric(angles_c_D_180) ~ b,  ylim=c(-360,360))
points(pred_degr ~ newdata,type="l")
points(predbis_degre ~ newdata,type="l",col="green")

```
````

Comment: This still seems to miss the definition of `angleRemap`. Where is it from?